# Apache permissions messed

Tags: linux, apache2

I was messing around with my privileges and I think I messed it all up. Is there a way to set all the default privileges installed with apache2. I'm fairly new to linux and was just learning as I was going.

I am getting the error

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server**.

The command I ran was `chmod -R 770 /*` which messed everything up.

Comment: Did you run it with `root`? Note that this means that no user can access to *any* dir in the server. The initial workaround would be to give 775 permissions. Let's move the question to [su] where they can give a more expert advise.

Comment: how do I move the question to super user? and yes i did it with root

Comment: I just voted to move it to that page. It needs 4 more votes. Otherwise, you can delete this question and directly ask in [su].

Comment: Did you really `chmod` your _entire_ system ? Please tell me you were not root. That forward slash is giving me the willies.

Comment: I know, i know... It was a VERY stupid thing to do lol..

Comment: You will, in all probability, need to reinstall your system.